# How to receive and send notifications to a SignalR hub while app (UWP) is suspended?

Tags: angularjs, azure, notifications, signalr, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows 10 application (UWP) which can send and receive notifications through a SignalR hub. Everything works perfectly and clients (an AngularJS webapp) are able to also send and receive notifications.

The problem is, when the UWP app goes to a suspended state (Windows Mobile goes to lock screen or whatever), the connection is lost (SignalR can't keep connection when app is not alive), and I lose ability to send/receive the notifications.

I would like to find a way to be able to send and receive notifications, even if the UWP app is not alive. I've heard about Notification Hub on Azure, but I don't know if it solves my issue and if it's possible to plug this into my AngularJS webapp.

**EDIT** May I prevent my app being suspended by Windows? My app looks like a turn by turn navigation service, so I would like not to be suspended or worse, terminated (even though, it seems I can't avoid this behavior when the OS needs memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WNS/ Azure Notification Hubs to send a push notification to an individual authenticated user when your app is suspended. You will need to create a background task to do this. Your background task could send a message at an interval of 15 minutes or when it is waken up, by the toast notification.

[Using Maintenance triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/use-a-maintenance-trigger)

[Send push notifications to authenticated users](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-push-notifications-app-users/)

With this you could receive notifications to your app while it is suspended.